# Emacs' org-mode: how to automatically "process to PDF" on save?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, org-mode, emacs24, auctex

Org-mode's <kbd>C-cep</kbd> does `export as LaTeX and process to PDF`. **How can <kbd>C-cep</kbd> be executed on each <kbd>C-xs</kbd>?**

Also, in all likelihood this probably isn't *the* optimal solution, so feel free to propose something better. As it is now, I have to do *both* <kbd>C-cep</kbd> *and* <kbd>C-xs</kbd>.

### Final solution

A tiny modification of abo-abo's answer below that *doesn't* open the PDF, lets `Skim` pick up any change, and thus keeps the focus on Emacs.

```
(defun org-export-as-pdf ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (org-latex-export-to-pdf))

(add-hook 
 'org-mode-hook
 (lambda()
   (define-key org-mode-map 
       (kbd "<f5>") 'org-export-as-pdf)))
```

Also, one should upgrade Org to version 8 from a *fresh* Emacs session: that is, [no Org-command should be executed prior to installing with the package-manager](http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg70336.html). Otherwise you'll hit the `Invalid function: org-with-silent-modifications` bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
(defun org-export-as-pdf-and-open ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf)))

(add-hook 
 'org-mode-hook
 (lambda()
   (define-key org-mode-map 
       (kbd "<f5>") 'org-export-as-pdf-and-open)))
```

### UPD

This requires `org-mode` 8.0.0 and up. It's easily installed with `list-packages`.

Comment: I'm using `Skim` which auto-refreshes the `.pdf` file, so (I think) `org-export-as-pdf` (without `-and-open`) would suffice.   
Still, I tried your solution verbatim and got the **`Symbol's function definition is void: org-latex-export-to-pdf`** error.

Comment: You must use an older version of Org. Upgrade to 8.

Comment: I would put your function in the after-save-hook, to answer the OP's question:    (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'org-export-as-pdf-and-open)

Comment: It's not very productive to export every org file on save. I'm sure that OP would find it very annoying. Saving and exporting and opening with one button is better IMO.

Comment: You were right with Org 7. Though, now, thanks to the asynchronous export (in Org 8), you're not blocked anymore when exporting to PDF.